# How do I install a sink in a room that doesn't have a drain vent?

Tags: plumbing, vent, drain, drain-waste-vent

I want to install a sink in my attached garage where there is no existing plumbing.  I will be running new water supply and drain pipes to mains behind a nearby wall.  I'm concerned I will need a drain vent to avoid a slow or gurgling drain.

What is a good design to avoid plumbing problems once installed?

Comment: If you're adding new drain pipes, why can't you add a drain vent?

Comment: I don't plan on running a pipe up through the roof from my garage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yours is a not uncommon problem, so a solution does exist. For example, how might one vent a sink in an island in the center of a kitchen? I looked online, and it seems there are two common solutions. You can use what is called a vacuum breaker, which lets air into the line to prevent slow/gurgly drain problems without allowing sewer gases into the area. The second option is an island loop vent. Both are described clearly in [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20151004115444/http://www.familyhandyman.com/kitchen/how-to-plumb-an-island-sink/view-all).

Answer (score 5):

There is a vent that can be mounted to a pipe going about half way up a wall. In my basement, I have one on the backside of a wall (on an unfinished side). It has a check valve to prevent smells from the sewer pipes from getting into the room. You could put it in a box on the wall of your garage and cover it if desired with something that looks like a cabinet.
[image]

Comment: Note that not all jurisdictions accept this solution.