# How can I fit a trap on a sink bowl that's directly above the vertical drain pipe?

Tags: repair, drain, kitchen-sink

I am just replacing an old double bowl sink at a rental unit .  I put a new granite countertop in and now have a single bowl coming down the bottom .  The sink and pipe going to the ground is just about directly underneath each other maybe a half inch off .

I'm having a real hard time fitting the swivel on with the P-trap .  No matter how close I push it is just not enough to get there .  I did read that we can use a rubber coupling and maybe have that work ?

[image: Is there a place post a picture]

Comment: Please post the picture to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and add a link to it here, then we can do the rest :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel https://imgur.com/a/zfzCN

Comment: [flexible drain line](https://www.google.com/search?q=flexible+drain+line&biw=1024&bih=639&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzhtqxkcfOAhUC3GMKHVOkAPgQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=kitchen+sink+flexible+drain+line&imgrc=mX4oXjaOE9eVeM%3A)

Comment: I don't like flex drains but this looks like the best option to me +.

Comment: Any possibility of moving the drain line?  Even if you get the trap connected, you'll be left with an S-trap. S-traps are no longer allowed by most plumbing codes, as they tend to have siphon problems.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a joint under that escutcheon?

If so, why not run an elbow toward the back wall, then  an elbow upward to a vertical pipe, then an elbow forward to a conventional p-trap?

This would effectively reduce the risk of siphoning water that an s-trap creates.

[image: trap]

If there is not enough distance in back of the pipe, the whole elbow/p-trap thing could be canted to one side or the other.

One or more joints could be eliminated if you can find a run of pipe with an integrated elbow. The lower horizontal run is needed only if the elbows don't move the vertical pipe far enough back to accommodate the p-trap.

Comment: Could you make a little drawing of that. I can visualize what you see and yes there is enough room in the back or side to side. That pipe disconnects from the bottom of the cabinet inside.

Comment: I appreciate everybody's help this is a really great place to learn.

Comment: Updated with illustration.

Comment: That is awesome I can figure that out.  Last question does the kitchen need a vent in the sink if it's an older house?

Comment: Code generally requires some type of vent, but I defer to my wiser plumbing friends on certain exceptions and specialized under-sink vents. Was the existing drain vented? Perhaps in the wall?

Comment: There is a discussion of missing vents in [this post](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/how-do-i-install-a-sink-in-a-room-that-doesnt-have-a-drain-vent).